# Лучшее решение для управления винторулевой колонкой (360°) на модели судна

Tags: робототехника

Необходимо полное вращение и контроль позиции. Какой тип двигателя выбрать?:

- Изначально думал что сервопривод полного вращения подойдет. Но насколько я понял все сервоприводы полного вращения не имеют контроля позиции. Поэтому не годится.
- Обычный двигатель с энкодером(датчик холла). Можно управлять положением при помощи ПИД регулятора зная начальную позицию.
- Шаговый двигатель. Тоже самое, но процесс управления проще. Достаточно указать шаги.
  Но в обоих случаях нужна начальная позиция. Самое простое решение - сделать некоторый индикатор(концевик) начального положения и при включении искать его.

Существуют ли еще какие-то решения? Например, мне кажется было бы идеально иметь двигатель с энкодером именно абсолютной позиции. Т.е. чтобы можно было от энкодера получить не импульсы, а текущее положение. (в простейшем случае что-то вроде переменного резистора с круговым вращением) Но я не знаю существуют ли вообще такие. Я пока не нашел.

PS.Модель судна небольшая и бюджет тоже. Выбирать приходится из того, что стоит не дорого и можно купить на алике/хоббийном магазине. Т.е. серьезные промышленные решения не подойдут.

Comment: *"все сервоприводы полного вращения не имеют контроля позиции"* - ¿почему нет? ¿А если и не имеют, что мешает его добавить?

Comment: В вопросе имеется ввиду, что "дешевые и доступные на aliexpress не имеют " и далее по тексту. В принципе они существуют https://emanual.robotis.com/docs/en/dxl/x/xl330-m077/ или сервомоторы [lego](https://www.lego.com/en-ie/product/ev3-medium-servo-motor-45503) (кстати клоны всего $14 на али).